# Check if string array exists in list of string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have a list of string arrays. I make a new string array through an iteration and try to put it inside the list, but it doesn't check to see if it exists when i use the contain function, and instead inserts duplicates.

```
List<string[]> possibleColumnValues = new List<string[]>();

while(true){

  string[] rArr = new string[5];
  //some code to populate the string goes here

  if (!possibleColumnValues.Contains(rArr){
  {
      possibleColumnValues.Add(rArr);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static bool AllElementInList(List<string[]> list, string[] arr)
{
    return list.Select(ar2 => arr.All(ar2.Contains)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Use it as :

```
        List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
        string[] arr;

        bool flag = AllElementInList(list, arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Still not very efficient but should do the trick:

```
if (!possibleColumnValues.Any(rArr.SequenceEqual))
{
    possibleColumnValues.Add(rArr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Contains` method relies upon the `Equals` method of its elements to see if it contains a particular value. Arrays do not override the default implementation of `Equals` so `Contains` will only consider an array to be equal to one already within in the the list if it is a reference to the same object (the default behaviour of `Equals`).

To work around this you can use the `Enumerable.Any()` extension method along with the `SequenceEqual` extension method:

```
if (!possibleColumnValues.Any(item.SequenceEqual))
{
    possibleColumnValues.Add(rArr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sequence equal method to compare two string arrays.

SequenceEqual extension from System.Linq in the C# language, you can test two collections for equality in one statement.

[SequenceEqual](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sequenceequal)

but its performance is much worse than alternative implementations.

or Implement your own Equals function

[List.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx)