# Find index of an array in List of arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

If you had a List of arrays like:

```
List<int[]> ListOfArrays = new List<int[]>();
ListOfArrays.Add(new int[] { 1, 1 });
ListOfArrays.Add(new int[] { 2, 1 });
```

How would you find the index of { 2, 1} in the List?

I do not want to use an iteration loop. I would like a concise method like the one suggested by PaRiMaL RaJ in [Check if string array exists in list of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884850/check-if-string-array-exists-in-list-of-string):

```
list.Select(ar2 => arr.All(ar2.Contains)).FirstOrDefault();
```

(the above code will return true if members of a given string array exist in a list of string arrays)

Comment: The only way to avoid an iteration loop will be a dictionary respectively a hash-lookup-table.

Comment: @xXliolauXx By iteration I think he means LINQ instead of a hand written loop.

Comment: Does the order of the internal array matter?

Comment: @Yuval ah I see... I thought it was the performance he wanted to keep high... And I thought of LinQ using loops too...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var myArr = new int[] { 2, 1 };
List<int[]> ListOfArrays = new List<int[]>();
ListOfArrays.Add(new int[] { 1, 1 });
ListOfArrays.Add(new int[] { 4, 1 });
ListOfArrays.Add(new int[] { 1, 1 });
ListOfArrays.Add(new int[] { 2, 1 });

int index = ListOfArrays.FindIndex(l => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(myArr, l));
```

Comment: You can shorten it a bit: `ListOfArrays.FindIndex(l => l.SequenceEqual(myArr));`

Comment: `ListOfArrays.FindIndex(myArr.SequenceEqual);` should also work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SequenceEqual` method for this. See MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks Markus, I would have to use a foreach loop over the List and check each member. There should be a more clever way.. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
List<int[]> ListOfArrays = new List<int[]>();
ListOfArrays.Add(new int[] { 1, 1 });
ListOfArrays.Add(new int[] { 2, 1 });
var chk = ListOfArrays.FindIndex(e => (e.SequenceEqual(new int[] { 2, 1 })));
```